# Show and hide several fields using Javascript

Tags: javascript, hide, show

I'm trying to do hide and show of several select and text fields

the idea is that in the first field when "Banco" is selected it shows a dropdown for the user to select which bank, till that part everything works perfectly fine, the problem comes when in the next "banco" dropdown people select "otros" it should show a text field for the costumer to write the name of the bank, but I have done everything and can't seem to make it work

Can you help me please??

this is the JS

```
function formapago() {
if (document.getElementById('infopago').value == 'banco') {
    document.getElementById('banco').style.display = '';
    document.getElementById('tipopago').style.display='';
    }   

else {
          document.getElementById('banco').style.display = 'none';
          document.getElementById('tipopago').style.display='none';
}

if (document.getElementById('infopago').value == 'mp') {
    document.getElementById('mpcobro').style.display = '';
} else {
          document.getElementById('mpcobro').style.display = 'none';
}  
if (document.getElementById('banco').value == 'otros') {
    document.getElementById('otrosban').style.display = '';
    }   

else {
          document.getElementById('otrosban').style.display = 'none';
}
```

}

and HTLM

```
<select name="infopago" id="infopago" onchange='formapago()'>
          <option value="elegir" selected="selected">Elegir</option>
          <option value="banco">Banco</option>
          <option value="mp">Mercado Pago</option>
        </select>
        </p>
        <div id="banco" style="display: none">
      <p><strong>BANCO: </strong></p>
      <p>
        <label for="banco">Banco Emisor</label>
        <select name="banco" id="banco" onchange='formapago()'>
          <option value="elegir" selected="selected">Elegir</option>
          <option value="provincial">Provincial</option>
          <option value="mercantil">Mercantil</option>
          <option value="banesco">Banesco</option>
          <option value="venezuela">Venezuela</option>
          <option value="otros">Otro</option>
        </select>
      </p> </div>

      <div id="otroban" style="display: none">
      <p>
        <label for="otroban">Otro Banco</label>
        <input type="text" name="otroban" id="otroban"/>
      </p>
      </div>
```

Comment: You really should be using a javascript framework like jQuery. It makes issues like this pretty trivial.

Comment: I tried to use jQuery but I'm already using it as it's a form converted in wizard and for some reason jQuery code doesn't work, that is why I'm trying to do it this way, if you could help me I would appreciate it

Comment: Put this in a Js fiddle and we can fix it. Nothing complicated.

Comment: Which wizard plugin you are using?

Comment: I'm using this one http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/turn-any-webform-into-a-powerful-wizard-with-jquery-formtowizard-plugin/ and it works great but my boss wants to the fields to appear of thin air and that it was working great till that second dropbox

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you have two element with same ID.

This part :

```
  <div id="banco" style="display: none">
    <p><strong>BANCO: </strong></p>
    <p>
      <label for="banco">Banco Emisor</label>
      <select name="banco" id="banco" onchange='formapago()'>
       <option value="elegir" selected="selected">Elegir</option>
       <option value="provincial">Provincial</option>
       <option value="mercantil">Mercantil</option>
       <option value="banesco">Banesco</option>
       <option value="venezuela">Venezuela</option>
       <option value="otros">Otro</option>
       </select>
    </p> 
 </div>
```

div and select element have id="banco".
Try to change select id.

**EDIT**

Here some problem i found when i see your HTML :

1. Multiple element with same id.
2. In your javascript, it try to get tipopago and mpcobro element, where is the element ?
3. I think this part :

> ```
>   document.getElementById('otrosban').style.display = '';
> ```

Should be :

> ```
>   document.getElementById('otroban').style.display = '';
> ```

Comment: Hi I didn't include that the part of tipopago or mpcobro because those 2 are working perfectly fine... But I'm glad to say that with the id change and the otroban that scaped my eyes (must be because it's 2:45am) it's fixed!! Thank youuuuu!!!